# Add bazel angular lint rule

Tags: angular, eslint, bazel

Do we have possibility to add eslint tool to the bazel build of [test project](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/tree/stable/examples/angular)? I can create PR to test project, but I need a short suggestion from which point I need to start.

Answer (score 1):

Gerrit has a `eslint` test rule that you could probably use or build upon:
https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/gerrit/blob/master/tools/js/eslint.bzl